# Outputting a class function from class object held in a vector

Tags: c++, class, object, vector

For a project in my C++ class I have to save some shape class objects into a vector then use them later to return the area of those shapes. My classes run fine but I don't know how to get back to any of the old class objects so that I can use them later in the program. Where I need to save the area to another text file I just can't find a way to get the correct results from the vector before I send it out.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include "Shape.h"
#include "Triangle.h"
#include "Rect.h"


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream inFS;
    double a = 0;
    double b = 0;
    double c = 0;
    vector <Rect> vRect;
    vector <Triangle> vTriangle;

    Rect Rect;
    Triangle Tri;

inFS.open("rSides.txt");
if(!inFS.is_open())
{
    cout << "Could not open rSides.txt." << endl;
    return 1;
}

while(inFS.good())
{
    cout << "Reading two numbers from rSides.txt" << endl;
    inFS >> a >> b;
    Rect.setHeight(a);
    Rect.setWidth(b);

    if(Rect.checkValidity()==true)
    vRect.push_back(Rect);

    else
    cout << "Invalid Input" << endl;
}

cout << vRect.size() << endl;

for(int i=0;i<vRect.size();i++)
    Rect = vRect.at(i);

    cout << Rect.getArea();
}
```

Comment: The question does not make much sense. It seems that you have skipped some words.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that at some point in my earlier attempts I had done something wrong. All I needed to do to call the class in the state that I wanted was:

```
cout << vRect[i].getArea();
```

I thought I had done that and gotten errors but it would appear that I'm just mistaken.